# FFmpeg scene detection with start and end frame

Tags: ffmpeg

I am working on a tool to display scene start and scene end.

```
ffmpeg -i "video.mp4" -filter_complex "select='gt(scene,0.3)',metadata=print:file=Scenes.txt" -vsync vfr scn_%%03d.jpg
```

Following command generates start frame of the scene. How can I generate last frame of the scene with ffmpeg.

Comment: This short and simple approach does not warrant an answer, but I'd say the easiest way is to check where the starting frame of the next scene is and then stepping back one frame

Comment: The select filter will not identify end frame, only scene start frames, so subtract one as @RivenSkaye said.

Comment: Seeking will work. But is more time consuming.